# Is a Selenium test case a macro?

Tags: selenium, macros

The [Selenium documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/) says Selenium's purpose is to test web apps. It refers to the things made in the Selenium IDE as "test cases". They look to me like macros, i.e., automated processes that one can record and play back. I'm not interested in testing web apps, but I need a good tool for making a macro to run in Firefox.

I'm not impressed with [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/), which seems to be clunky and poorly documented. Selenium seems to be well-designed and well-documented. Ironically, Selenium is completely free, while fully functional iMacros is expensive.

Is a Selenium test case the same as a macro? Can I just think "macro" when they say "test case," or am I missing something if I think so?

Or another way to put the question would be: What is the difference, if any, between a Selenium test case and a macro?

---

**Edit:** After writing the above, I tried to make a macro in Selenium IDE and found that there were some things that it did not record. This suggests to me that this system is not really adequate to making generalized macros that reproduce anything I can do in the browser. (I wrote about what I'm trying to do in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019747/how-to-automate-saving-webpages).) Those two things are:

- When I right-clicked on a link and typed "A" to store the linked URL, Selenium did not add anything to the algorithm it was recording.
- When I typed `Alt-F-A` and saved the page, Selenium again did nothing.

Is it true that Selenium cannot make macros that include these operations, or is that something that Kantu (mentioned in Tim Vanderzeil's comment below) can do but Selenium alone cannot, or am I doing something wrong and Selenium can make macros with those tasks if I know what I'm doing?